# Google API calls slowing down the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

My website built on Rails 4.0.3 uses the `google-api-client` gem to authenticate and query the Google Analytics API for analytics data.
I use this analytics data to build simple sparklines for my blog posts.

The data I am querying constitutes pageviews for a period of 30 days.

To that end, I have organized my code into a helper file and a model.
I am not sure if this the correct approach, because when I load my admin page, it slows down to a crawl.

`pageviews.rb`

```
class Pageviews < ActiveRecord::Base
#google analytics api shenanigans
require 'google/api_client'
require 'date'
include ReportingHelper

def self.getviews post
client, analytics, parameters = ReportingHelper.initclient
result   = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.management.profiles.list, parameters: parameters)
profiles = result.data.items

parameters = {
  'ids'         => PROFILE,
  'start-date'  => (Date.today - 30).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
  'end-date'    => Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
  'metrics'     => "ga:pageviews",
  'dimensions'  => "ga:date",
  'filters'     => "ga:pagePath=~/#{post}"
}
result = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.ga.get, :parameters => parameters)
interim = result.data.rows.map{|hit| hit[1].to_i}.join(', ')

end

end
```

`reporting_helper.rb`

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'date'

module ReportingHelper

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'my_email'
KEY_PATH = File.join(Rails.root, '/config/', 'mykey.p12')
PROFILE = 'ga:123456'

def self.initclient
client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => 'rishighan.com', :application_version => '1')

key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(KEY_PATH, 'notafoo')
service_account = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction'],
key)
client.authorization = service_account.authorize
analytics = client.discovered_api('analytics', 'v3')

parameters = {
  'accountId' => '~all',
  'webPropertyId' => '~all'
}

return client, analytics, parameters
end

end
```

I am using an `array.map` method to extract values out of the response and then using `join` to create a comma-separated sequence of integers for the sparklines plugin to use.

I know that this operation is expensive and is the one at fault for slowing the page down.

I want to know if there is a right way to handle these expensive API requests.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing a new API request to Google is very expensive!

You should use low level caching `Rails.cache.fetch` to cache the API data.
You could even use a worker to asynchronously send API calls, so your service won't be slowed down.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at the low level caching docs on the Rails website. I have the following request `result = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.ga.get, :parameters => parameters)` Should this go in `Rails.cache.fetch(?, :expires_in => 12.hours)`  ?

Comment: Ok take in mind that `Rails.cache.fetch` executes the block you passed to the function, caches and return its block return value if no cache or an expired one is found. Otherwise if a valid cache is found it will only fetch the old result and return it. So in your case `result = Rails.cache.fetch('google_analytics_api/cache_name', expires_in: 2.hours) { client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.ga.get, :parameters => parameters) } ` should work as expected. Dont forget to change the cache name based on your user/tenant/anything else

Comment: I tried this and got `no _dump_data is defined for class OpenSSL::PKey::RSA`